# Another way to say 'also'

Tags: word-usage

I use the word 'also' a lot when writing paragraphs.  When I find myself using 'also' twice in the same paragraph, it feels a bit awkward.  Is there another word or phrase I should be using?

Answer (score 3):

Likewise: [moreover; in addition; also; too](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/+likewise) but is you are making a list, the word '[item](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/item)' replaces 'also' too.  The terms **moreover, additionally, secondly, withal, what is more, furthermore** may be more appropriate for your purpose

Answer (score 1):

*Plus* may also be an alternative.

This is a nice house, plus there is a big private garden.